# SSL and  Amazon AWS java SDK

Tags: java, ssl, amazon-ec2

i have a problem with my application: i must integrate a request to Amazon EC2 in a flow that use an own SSL connection.
So to launch my application i must use this command:

java -cp . -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=config/serverkeys -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypass -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=config/serverkeys -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypass -jar app.jar

but Amazon EC2 answer with : Unable to execute HTTP request: peer not authenticated

If i remove the trusstore part, so i use only java -cp . -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=config/serverkeys -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypass, everything goes well.
It seems that i need an Amazon EC2 certificate in my trusstore...

Anyone has good idea about this?
Thanks,
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the same file for both keystore and truststore. You need a private key and a certificate that Amazon will trust in your keystore. Your truststore contains public certificates that *you* trust, i.e. Amazon's in this case, and this is what you presently don't have, hence the error. If the SSL server uses a CA-signed certificate, you don't need your own truststore at all, the default one that comes with the JRE will do.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the Amazon Ec2 Certificate?

Comment: From my error, Is it possible to understand if Amazon doesn't accept connection from me or my application doesn't accept connection from amazon?

Comment: Amazon doesn't trust your certificate, or it didn't even get sent. Run your application with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake and post the output and I'll tell you which it was.

Comment: @Max other way about actually, your truststore doesn't tesurvMason's certificate. Are you using the default Java truststore as per above?

Comment: i use a  custom trustore. If i use the default Java Trustore i can connect to ec2 but my application thread do not communicate with each other. But i should use the custom trustore because my application is a part oh another bigger application.

Comment: Your custom truststore doesn't trust the Amazon cettificate

Comment: @Max You don't need the Amazon certificate specifically, you just need the CA root certificates. That are shipped in the default Java truststore. If you're constructing truststores you do need to know what's in them :-)

Comment: @Max, yes, and I already did. Either use the standard Java truststore, or at least use it as a starting point when building your own, or import the Amazon certificate into your custom truststore.

Comment: Thanks EJP, i resolved in this way: i generated a key and put in a custom keystore; i create a certificate and put in default java trust ore. All goes well now.